# [fixed]Wordpress use lots of CPUs and cannot stop

Tags: wordpress

In the Apache access log, I found all the connections are from my own site IP and it keeps doing this every second. Any idea what could cause this problem? Thanks.

xx.xx.xx.xx.xx - - [11/Nov/2010:12:30:26 -0800] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.0" 200 80604 "-" "WordPress/3.0.1; http://domain.com/blog"

xx.xx.xx.xx.xx - - [11/Nov/2010:12:30:27 -0800] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.0" 200 80604 "-" "WordPress/3.0.1; http://domain.com/blog"

Also, the mysql will generate a new process every second. I have disabled all wordpress plugins and this site does not have much traffic.

Id   | User      | Host            | db                   | Command | Time | State | Info
             |
+------+-----------+-----------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 3335 | dbuser | localhost       | db_name  | Sleep   | 0    |       |                  |
| 3336 | dbuser | localhost       | db_name  | Sleep   | 10   |       |                  |
| 3337 | dbuser | localhost       | db_name  | Sleep   | 9    |       |                  |
| 3341 | dbuser | localhost       | db_name  | Sleep   | 8    |       |                  |
| 3342 | dbuser | localhost       | db_name  | Sleep   | 7    |       |                  |
| 3344 | dbuser | localhost       | db_name  | Sleep   | 6    |       |                  |
| 3345 | dbuser | localhost       | db_name  | Sleep   | 5    |       |                  |

++++Fixed the problem++++
It's because the RSS widget used wrong url

Comment: This isn't a forum, please see the FAQ (top right corner of every page). Please add the solution as an answer to your question (bottom of this page), then mark it as the correct answer (green checkmark next to the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be the same problem you're experiencing, but Jeff Atwood [has blogged about](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/behold-wordpress-destroyer-of-cpus.html) Wordpress taking up insane amounts of CPU before. Essentially, the solution he found was that wordpress isn't caching properly, and installing a plugin to improve caching performance. [WP-SuperCache](http://ocaoimh.ie/wp-super-cache/%5C) seems to be the most recently updated of the bunch. You may want to see if giving a caching plugin a try solves your problems.

Comment: This is not my blog. I am going to install the wp-supercache plugin if I get the access to the panel. But this problem only happens recently. Thanks.